# Wampserver not able to connect to API

Tags: jquery, html, api, networking, wampserver

I'm currently learning HTML and have attempted to setup a Wampserver to work on. Everything is working fine and I am able to access my site from other networks over the internet and such. However, I am trying to use an API ([this one](https://github.com/Seems2Legit/Rainbow-Six-Siege-Player-Stats-API), specifically.) When I do the GET request, it appears to not be able to connect as I get "User not found" each time. I know that my code is correct as I tried throwing the exact site up on a free online webhost and all is fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use **XAMPP, WAMP** sometimes fail with APIS